# Need help importing NodeJS-Module "htmlparser2" in SmartMobileStudio

Tags: javascript, node.js, smart-mobile-studio

I tried to use the htmlparser2 module (installed via `npm install htmlparser2`) in SmartMobileStudio. The module itself works well in direct javascript (using a slightly changed sample from [htmlparser2's Homepage](https://npmjs.org/package/htmlparser2)):

```js
var htmlparser = require("htmlparser2");
var parser = new htmlparser.Parser({
    onopentag: function(name, attribs){
        console.log(name);
        console.log(attribs);
    }
});
parser.write("<img src='image1.jpg'>");
parser.end();
```

Using SMS (2.0.0.9 Beta) I tried to import the module like this:

```pas
unit NodeJS.htmlparser2;

interface

uses
  NodeJS.Core,
  NodeJS.events;

type
  TOnTag = procedure(name: string; attribs: Variant);
  TOnText = procedure(text: string);

  JParser = class external(NodeJS.events.JNodeEventEmitter)
    procedure write(s: string);
    procedure &end;
  end;

  Jhtmlparser_Exports = class external
  public
    function Parser(onopentag: TOnTag; ontext: TOnText; onclosetag: TOnTag): JParser;
  end;

function htmlparser2: Jhtmlparser_Exports;

implementation

function htmlparser2: Jhtmlparser_Exports;
begin
  result := Jhtmlparser_Exports( require("htmlparser2") );
end;

end.
```

I changed the project generated by the Node.js-New-Project-Template like this:

```
[...]

procedure TServer.Run;
begin
  var htmlparser := NodeJS.htmlparser2.htmlparser2;

  var parser := htmlparser.Parser(
   procedure (Name: string; Attribs: Variant)
   begin
     console_.log([Name]);
     console_.log([Attribs]);
   end,
   nil,
   nil);

  parser.write("<img src='image1.jpg'>");
  parser.end();
end;
```

The Problem is that the emitted code is not correct, but nearly:

```js
[...]
parser = htmlparser.Parser(function (Name$3, Attribs) {
   console_().log([Name$3].slice());
   console_().log([Attribs].slice());
},null,null);
[...]
```

This works:

```js
[...]
parser = new htmlparser.Parser({onopentag: function (Name$3, Attribs) {
   console_().log([Name$3].slice());
   console_().log([Attribs].slice());
}});
[...]
```

The difference is the "new" keyword and the named event callback "onopentag". What do I need to write to generate working js code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a class can't be "exported" in pascal like you can with javascript and requirejs/nodejs, we need to use an external class trick: we can set some code for the external class name. 
Second, we need to supply an "options" object (more verbose but needed for type safety).

```
JParserOptions = class
  onopentag : TOnTag;
  ontext    : TOnText;
  onclosetag: TOnTag
end;

JParser = class external '(htmlparser2()).Parser' (NodeJS.events.JNodeEventEmitter)
  constructor Create(options: JParserOptions);

  procedure write(s: string);
  procedure &end;
end;
```

We can use this as follows:

```
var options = JParserOptions.Create;
options.onopentag := procedure (Name: string; Attribs: Variant)
  begin
    console_.log([Name]);
    console_.log([Attribs]);
  end;

var parser := new JParser(options);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. One question: In the string `'(htmlparser2()).Parser'` what is `htmlparser2()` referring to? It doesn't seem to be my own function.

Comment: @Stebi: "htmlparser2()" is the local function in "NodeJS.htmlparser2.pas", so it auto loads/requires the htmlparser library. This is the simplest (and ugliest?) solution to do it :). Btw: the "require" call loads the lib only once (has an internal cache).

Comment: Note: a better way (?) could be to make a full wrapper unit, which loads/requires the library the first time and keeps it in a variable, and using this variable to create exported classes etc in normal pascal (instead of the full external class solution)

Comment: The reason I asked was because I tried to rename my htmlparser2-function and it didn't work anymore. But I now found problem: It was smart linking feature of the compiler removing the function which wasn't called anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, I found a better solution: use a class reference (JParserClass = class of JParser)

```
  JParser = class external(NodeJS.events.JNodeEventEmitter)
    constructor Create(onopentag: TOnTag; ontext: TOnText; onclosetag: TOnTag);
    procedure write(s: string);
    procedure &end;
  end;
  JParserClass = class of JParser;

  Jhtmlparser_Exports = class external
  public
    Parser: JParserClass;
  end;
```

Then you can create the class like this:

```
  var parser := new (htmlparser2.Parser)(
```

Or like this:

```
  var parserclass = htmlparser2.Parser;
  var parser := new parserclass(
```

Or:

```
  var parserclass = htmlparser2.Parser;
  var parser := parserclass.Create(
```